# Creating a batch file to kill a process

Tags: java, batch-file, process, windows-server-2008

I currently have a work order system that runs on our web and sql server. Unfortunately we are not able to update to the latest version of the software and are stuck dealing with the issues that currently come with the older software. Nearly twice a day the Java processes reach a point where they freeze up the website and I have to manually log in and kill the process.

Instead of manually logging in and killing the process I was hoping to create a batch file that I could schedule to run twice a day, morning and afternoon, to preventatively kill the process. Or just create a file and save it to my desktop that would connect to the server and kill the process.

I'm not sure if this is possible but it would be awesome if someone could walk me through the coding for this script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps PsKill would work for you?
[PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx)

Its commandline, and you can use it to connect to another computer and kill a process there.

```
pskill [- ] [-t] [\\computer [-u user] [-p passwd]] <process name | process id>
```

If you make a batchfile that kills the process, you can make the batchfile start the process again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TASKKILL /IM program_name`

Run `TASKKILL /?` from a command prompt for more info.